# How I convert this jQuery function to AngularJS Directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this `onclick="startTimer({{ $index }},{{ product.time }})"` but for obviously reason the databindings doesn't render, so I have to use `ng-click`for rendering the values but `ng-click`no working with my jQuery Script

```
<script>
    function startTimer(id, time) {
        $("#" + id).next("div").removeClass("claimActive");
        $("#" + id).next("div").addClass("claimWait");
        $("#" + id).removeClass("timerActive");
        $("#" + id).addClass("timerWait");
        $("#" + id).next("div").children("a").text("WAIT");
        if (time <= 60) {
            if (time < 10) $("#" + id).children("#m").text("0" + time);
            else $("#" + id).children("#m").text(time);
            $("#" + id).children("#s").text("30");
        } else {
            if (time < 600) $("#" + id).children("#h").text("0" + time / 60);
            else $("#" + id).children("#h").text(time / 60);
            $("#" + id).children("#m").text("00");
            $("#" + id).children("#s").text("30");
        }
    }

    function checkTimers() {
        $(".timer").each(function() {
            seconds = parseInt($(this).children("#h").text()) * 3600 + parseInt($(this).children("#m").text()) * 60 + parseInt($(this).children("#s").text());
            if (seconds > 0) {
                hours = parseInt($(this).children("#h").text());
                min = parseInt($(this).children("#m").text());
                sec = parseInt($(this).children("#s").text());
                if (sec > 0) {
                    if (sec > 10) $(this).children("#s").text(sec - 1);
                    else $(this).children("#s").text("0" + (sec - 1));
                } else if (min > 0) {
                    if (min > 10) $(this).children("#m").text(min - 1);
                    else $(this).children("#m").text("0" + (min - 1));
                    $(this).children("#s").text(59);
                } else if (hours > 0) {
                    if (hours > 10) $(this).children("#h").text(hours - 1);
                    else $(this).children("#h").text("0" + (hours - 1));
                    $(this).children("#m").text(59);
                    $(this).children("#s").text(59);
                }
            } else {
                $(this).next("div").removeClass("claimWait");
                $(this).next("div").addClass("claimActive");
                $(this).addClass("timerActive");
                $(this).removeClass("timerWait");
                $(this).next("div").children("a").text("CLAIM");
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(checkTimers, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

So I Need this in AngularJS Directives, but I Don't have any idea how to do that all that I already add to my Controller is something like

`$scope.startTimer = function($index,productTime) {};`

Comment: You have to redesign it a little bit to fit into angular Paradigm well.

Comment: but the question is how? I really new in this, so I just have a minimum idea that is no enough for resolve this, this all I need for start the css of the project

Comment: learn angular basics. You don't change text using jQuery's text() method, you use angularJS binding. There is too much to tell you in a SO answers. CodeAcademy has a 2 hour course on angular for free, there are videos on youtube. Search "angularjs 1 hour".